# I am having trouble with a date field being displayed in a grid

Tags: date, extjs

I am having trouble with a date field being displayed in a Extjs grid. I am using php to do the query and return my data in json format. The database is SQL Server. The date is coming back in the json file as:
"TERMDATE":{"date":"2013-02-13 00:00:00","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"America/New_York"}

this is just the date field, there are other fields in the row and they all display properly.
I just want to display the date, should I be doing something in my php file or is there a way to pull the date out of what is being sent. The date field displays as [object Object] when the grid is refreshed.

Here is my SQL Statement:

```
SELECT CPK_USERS, FNAME, LNAME, STATUS, DEPARTMENT, Email, PHONE1, CellPhone, Work_Ext,   HIREDATE, SUPERVISOR, TERMDATE FROM USERS where DELFLAG = 0 and CPK_USERS > 0 order by FNAME
```

Here is the first record returned in json format:

```
{"succuss":true,"data":[{"CPK_USERS":153,"FNAME":"Aaron","LNAME":"Booth","STATUS":"Out","DEPARTMENT":"Customer Support","Email":"aaron.booth@xxxxx.com","PHONE1":"2134354709","CellPhone":"6357662738","Work_Ext":"550","HIREDATE":{"date":"2008-06-09 00:00:00","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"America\/New_York"},"SUPERVISOR":"","TERMDATE":{"date":"2013-02-13 00:00:00","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"America\/New_York"}},
```

My model:

```
Ext.define('DHS.model.dhsusers.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'CPK_USERS' },
        { name: 'FNAME' },
        { name: 'LNAME' },
        { name: 'STATUS' },
        { name: 'DEPARTMENT' },
        { name: 'Email' },
        { name: 'PHONE1' },
        { name: 'CellPhone' },
        { name: 'Work_Ext' },
        { name: 'HIREDATE' },
        { name: 'SUPERVISOR' },
        { name: 'TERMDATE' }
    ]
});
```

My View:

```
Ext.define('DHS.view.dhsusers.UserInfoList', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.userinfolist',
    frame: true,
    store: Ext.create('DHS.store.dhsusers.UserInfo'),
    columns:[
        {text:"CPK_Users", dataIndex:'CPK_USERS', flex:1, hidden: true, hideable: false},
        {text:"First Name", dataIndex:'FNAME', flex:1},
        {text:"Last Name", dataIndex:'LNAME', flex:1},
        {text:"Term Date", dataIndex:'TERMDATE', flex:1, type:'datecolumn'},
        {text:"Email", dataIndex:'Email', flex:1},
        {text:"Home Phone", dataIndex:'PHONE1', flex:1},
        {text:"Cell", dataIndex:'CellPhone', flex:1},
        {text:"Work Ext", dataIndex:'Work_Ext', flex:1}
    ]
});
```

Comment: Are you using a datecolumn?

Answer (score 0):

I gues you are using TERMDATE as grid column, if you use TERMDATE.date(teorically) you will get riht display. but if you share extjs codes that will be better.